# Has conda deleted my crontab file and my selenium module?

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, cron, conda

Recently I've installed conda (the package manager) on my Ubuntu.

Now whenever I open a terminal it appears like this:

> (base) myName$

I had a crontab task that I was expecting to run but when I checked, the crontab file was empty.

Also, I used to be able to run from the terminal a python script that used selenium. I still can run the program if I use the python IDLE, but now it doesn't work when I run it from the terminal. I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Is it possible that conda has done something to my files?

Comment: The conda base environment uses the Python executable that is installed with conda.  You are the scripts aren't working for you because they were written using the base Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I just had to run the cron demon because it had stopped.